# Query for days since I created data in db in Django

Tags: django, python-3.x, date

I have a date field that registers the created date of the object.

I want to see how many days have past, since I created that object. How can I do that in Django ?

I want to make something like

```
today_date - object_created_date = x days
```

This is my model:

```
class Comment(models.Model):
    created_date = models.DateTimeField()
    comment = models.CharField(max_length=500, default='', blank=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    post =models.ForeignKey(Post,related_name='comments',on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `timezone`, and create a property inside your Comment model.

```
from django.utils import timezone

class Comment(models.Model):
   ...
   # rest of your fields

   @property
   def since(self):
      return (timezone.now() - self.created_date).days
```

You can call `since` method using the comment object.

```
comment = Comment.objects.first()
comment.since
# output: 6
```

You can also call this method from the template as well.

```
{{ comment.since }}
```

> `since` will behave like a model field and it will return the number of days since that comment is created.

Answer (score 0):

Get the last created object in the database and subtract its created date from todays.

```
latest_comment = Comment.objects.all().latest('created_date')
time_since_creation_timdelta = django.utils.timezone.now() - latest_comment.created_date
# This is assuming your dates are timezone aware. Otherwise, just just use datetime.now instead of timezone.now.
days_past = time_since_creation.days
seconds_past = time_since_creation.seconds
hours_past = time_since_creation.hours
# etc... (see datetime.timedelta documentation for info on what else you get from a timdelta object)
```